# Getting the quickest times from a database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp

I have the following query which has 2 date fields which were generated using PHP's time().  I basically want to order the results so the row with the shortest difference between the 2 times is at the top.

Is the following query how I should be doing this?

```
select start_date, end_date
from date_table
order by end_date - start_date asc
```

The 2 columns contains times in the following formats

```
start_date - end_date
1379078542 - 1379078574
1379085000 - 1379085197
```

Where the first one has a difference of 32 seconds and the second one has a difference of 3 minutes and 17 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried this yet? What was the result?

Comment: It works, but I don't know if this is a recommended way of achieving this interms of speed/performance.

Comment: Are you joking? How could this possibly be improved? This is probably the simplest, most basic query I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
SELECT (`end_date`-`start_date`) as `time` FROM `table` ORDER BY `time` ASC
```